# Check if it is an integer or not

Tags: bash, validation, input, integer

I'm trying to handle the 'integer expression expected' error.
I need my input to be just integers.

I did a while loop to check it, but it's entering the loop even if it was an integer.

This is my code:

```
read -p "Number: " number

while [[ ! "$number" =~ '[0-9]' ]];
do

read -p "Reenter the number: " number

done
```

Is there another way?

Comment: The answers to your question are of course correct, but you don't need a regex for this. A wildcard pattern would work as well: `[[ $number == *[^0-9]* ]]` is true if `number` does not entirely contain of digits. I hope you are aware, that both versions (the regexp solutions in the answers and my wildcard solution) would classify a negative number as not-numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Number: " number

while [[ ! "$number" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];
do
    read -p "Reenter the number: " number
done
```

Answer (score 1):

By using quotes, you're telling bash the characters should be matched literally. And answering `[0-9]` or `xyz[0-9]abc` is really the way to exit the loop.

Don't quote the regex.

Moreover, you don't want to check that the string contains a digit. You want to check it doesn't contain anything else.

```
while [[ ! $number =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
```

- `^` stands for the *beginning of the string*
- `$` stands for the *end of the string*
- `+` means the's at least one digit

You can also just check for any non-digit:

```
while [[ $number =~ [^0-9] ]]
```

- `^` at the beginning of a character class negates it.